# Program a 27c512 eeprom?

Tags: eeprom

I have a W27C512 chip in my sights. This will be my first time using a programmable rom. I need to know how to convert any form of human-readable code into either HEX or BIN format. Here are the issues I need to solve (please correct me if i am mistaken):

I need to know the applicable addresses of the W27C512 chip. I also need to know the instruction set for this chip. ANY compiler will be handy. After spending half of today on this problem, the closest I have to an answer is this site: [Proj19-EEprom programmer 27C512](http://nadergator.com/proj19.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK Memories don't have an instruction set. Thy may have some commands to do a bulk erase or so.

In your case you have to know how big is your program/data and what addresses it will occupy.

You don't need a compiler. All you need is:

1. Device programmer (physical hardware)
2. Your data to be programmed in i-HEX format or
3. Your data to be programmed in S-record format or
4. Your data in binary format

Here are your answers taken from the device datasheet:

[image]

[image]

**Edit:** On second thoughts: you can build your own programmer as I did long time back using dip switches, de-bounce circuit, push-button for PGM and LOTS of TIME :)

Answer (score 0):

Also, this thread may be helpful: http://www.eevblog.com/forum/microcontrollers/help-in-copying-a-set-of-eprom-%2827c256%29-and-programable-memory-9306/15/

[Edit]

Actually, it looks like EPROM programmers are available inexpensively on eBay and Amazon. An obstacle has been that historically EPROM programmers for older chips ran off PC parallel port, which is not so viable with present-day machines. So I was happy to see that eBay-available units include ones driven from USB.